# Jolt transformation of array element

Tags: java, json, jolt

I am trying to convert below input json using jolt

```json
{
  "Notification": {
    "product": {
      "version": 1,
      "concepts": {
        "concept": [
          {
            "records": {
              "record": [
                {
                  "attributes": {
                    "attribute": [
                      {
                        "name": "IsListed",
                        "content": "N"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              ]
            },
            "cversion": 1,
            "cname": "ListingInfo"
          },
          {
            "records": {
              "record": [
                {
                  "attributes": {
                    "attribute": [
                      {
                        "name": "Code",
                        "content": "ABCD"
                      },
                      {
                        "name": "Value",
                        "content": "Vall"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              ]
            },
            "cversion": 1,
            "cname": "Reference"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The output I expect is given below. If the input contains multiple attribute blocks for a concept, then the output should start with an array **`[{},{}]`** otherwise it should start with **`{}`**

```json
{
  "version": 1,
  "ListingInfo": {
    "name": "IsListed",
    "content": "N"
  },
  "Reference": [
    {
      "name": "Code",
      "content": "ABCD"
    },
    {
      "name": "Value",
      "content": "Vall"
    }
  ]
}
```

The spec that I am using is given below

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "Notification": {
        "product": {
          "version": "version",
          "concepts": {
            "concept": {
              "*": {
                "records": {
                  "record": {
                    "*": {
                      "attributes": {
                        "attribute": {
                          "*": {
                            "name": "@(7,cname).[&1].&",
                            "content": "@(7,cname).[&1].&"
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

The output of the above spec produces an array even if there is only one element

```json
{
  "version": 1,
  "ListingInfo": [
    {
      "name": "IsListed",
      "content": "N"
    }
  ],
  "Reference": [
    {
      "name": "Code",
      "content": "ABCD"
    },
    {
      "name": "Value",
      "content": "Vall"
    }
  ]
}
```

What change is required in my spec to correct the array issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove square brackets to convert the notation from `.[&1].` to `.&1.` in your case, then call looping within an extra **shift** transformation spec, where no need to use square brackets, the array will be spontaneously formed for multiple objects stated on the common node, such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "@Notification.product": {
        "version": "&", // use replacement operator "&"
        "@concepts.concept": {
          "*": {
            "@records.record": {
              "*": {
                "@attributes.attribute": {
                  "*": {
                    "*": "@5,cname.&1.&" // combine individual attributes within a single line
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "version": "&",
      "*": {
        "*": "&1"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is :

[image]